# Paasing an object into an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Have an object that needs to be pass inside the array of source using javascript,throwing an error **spec is undefined** when using `push` function. will push function work for this scenario

```js
var a = [
  "name": "ben",
  "type": "male",
  "appType": "human",

  "spec": {
    "view": "instanceview",
    "sink": {
      "source": [{
          "data": {
            "path": "google/path",
            "name": "test",
            "Id": "11234",
          },
          "ref": "www.xyz.com",
          "id": "isdfjsbfjsfb",
          "resourceType": "app"
        }
      ],
    },
  },
}]

var b = {
  "data": {
    "path": "google/path",
    "name": "goldengate",
    "Id": "11234vndslknvlsmnv",
  },
  "ref": "www.xyz.com",
  "id": "6452367e5375",
  "resourceType": "app"
}

a.spec.sink.source.push(b);
```

would expect `b` to be pushed to `source`

Comment: `a` has invalid structure (missing `{` after `[`). Please post exact error message and fix your code to let us reproduce your issue. Note that `a` is an array, so you propably just need `a[0].spec.sink.source.push(b);`

Answer (score 0):

An array with `string` keys is not a valid structure, you need to convert `a` to an object

```
var a = { // <-- here
    "name": "ben",
    "type": "male",
    "appType": "human",
    "spec": {
        "view": "instanceview",
        "sink": {
            "source": [
                {
                    "data": {
                        "path": "google/path",
                        "name": "test",
                        "Id": "11234",

                    },
                    "ref": "www.xyz.com",
                    "id": "isdfjsbfjsfb",
                    "resourceType": "app"
                }

            ],
        },
    },
} // <-- here
```

Comment: Although it's a valid point, I think looking at the OP, it might just be a copy paste error, as he seems to end with `}]`, so that `a` might be an array with object inside it?